# Adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to private NuGet

Tags: .net-core, nuget

Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package has a gazillion dependencies and pushing each to a private NuGet instance is heinous.  Is there any good / easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library here will download all NuGet dependencies of your package and then you can add each file to nuget separately.

https://github.com/StuffOfInterest/NuGetDependencyDownloader

Comment: Why do you need to download them while .NET Core SDK has offline cache? https://blog.lextudio.com/offline-publishing-asp-net-core-apps-cf22f45158af